# How to create a table like structure in drupal content type?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am almost there with this but cannot seem to get this functionality going as planned.

I am creating a questionnaire using drupal content type. What I am trying to do is to create a table like structure as below in content type. The second and third column contain check boxes  and first column data(i.e computer, internet) and first row(i.e Everyone have access , Nobody have access) are taxonomy terms . Is it possible to display like this in content type by using some modules in drupal? Anybody have any better suggestions?

```
|           | Everyone have access | Nobody have access |
---------------------------------------------------------
| Computers |           1          |         2          |
---------------------------------------------------------
| Internet  |           1          |         2          |
---------------------------------------------------------
| Fax       |           1          |         2          |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: hi i dont believe there is contrib module for this purpose but u can bring this functionality simpley using custom moduel

Comment: "_fisrt column contain data_": What do you mean by data? Also, what is the purpose of this? You want to bulk add taxonomy terms to nodes?

Comment: @TheodorosPloumis As I mentioned this is for creating a questionnaire for organisation survey.This is to check how available are the technological sources(i.e computer, internet, etc) at organization. The first column term such as internet and computer are taxonomy terms which should be taken from taxonomy and yes I want to bulk add the the taxonomy terms to nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Term Level Field](http://drupal.org/project/term_level) module. This module provides a field type for referencing terms with a level to an entity.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Editable fields](https://drupal.org/project/editablefields) with [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) module. Of course, if you didn't need such a display (table forms) you should use [Views Bulk Operations](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) modules.

If you need to do this in a node use [Tableform](https://drupal.org/project/tableform) module. But if you want to show nodes whike editing a node it is the same. A node should not be used for tasks just for content.

Comment: Is there any way to display table forms in content type itself. These modules you mentioned display table forms only in views only.